# How to handle directory separator character in japanese and korean?

Tags: c#

In Japanese and Korean they use different directory separator characters, respectively ¥ and ₩. How do you handle this in a C# application ?

For instance, my application checks if a particular directory exists : "Binaries/Win64", but that doesn't seem to work on korean systems, and I suspect the issue comes from that directory separator character.

Should I change all paths to reflect this, for example : $"Binaries{Path.DirectorySeparatorCharacter}Win64", or is there a better way ?

My app also run the command line program unrealpaktool, which uses a text file containing paths of files to include in the resulting pak. Should this file also use culture specific directory separators ?

Comment: I would probably use `String.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorCharacter);`

Comment: Consider using [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) for constructing paths,